# Populate JQuery datatable with JSON data from a variable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have JSON data in a hidden variable (using old school postback, not ajax calls). I have written below code to populate the same into a datatable.

```
var BatchDataList = JSON.parse($('#BatchDataJSON').val());
$('#BatchListTable').DataTable(
{
    'data': BatchDataList,
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            data: "BatchID"
        },
        {
            data: "BatchType"
        },
        {
            data: "CreatedDate"
        },
        {
            data: "IsBatchCompleted"
        }
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    responsive: true,
    "scrollX": true,
});
```

The actual table definition is below.

```
<table id="BatchListTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable" style="width: 100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Batch ID</th>
                                        <th>Batch Type</th>
                                        <th>Create Date</th>
                                        <th>Completed</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody runat="server">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

When running this code, I get error saying "Request parameter unknown". I thought my JSON might be invalid. But that seems to be fine. Here is an example.

```
[{"BatchID":"31-a1eac15c","CreatedDate":"2018-12-19T11:51:18.577","IsBatchCompleted":false,"BatchType":"Conversion"},
{"BatchID":"31-b3e8cc7e","CreatedDate":"2018-12-19T10:18:51.27","IsBatchCompleted":false",BatchType":""}]
```

I think it is a problem with the way I am assigning JSON to the datatable. But I can't seem to figure out what I am missing here.

P.S. I tried using the variable's value directly, without parsing. Same issue in that case also.

Comment: first look `"IsBatchCompleted":false"BatchType":""` needs to add `comma` after `false`

Comment: Oops. That was my mistake when copying the json. Had to remove some columns with confidential data, and I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to put targets property in the columndefs:
But you need to sort your data columns according to your table.**

```
var BatchDataList = JSON.parse($('#BatchDataJSON').val());
$('#BatchListTable').DataTable(
{
    'data': BatchDataList,
    'columnDefs': [
       {targets: 0}
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    responsive: true,
    "scrollX": true,
});
```

Sort JSON according to table columns:

```
[{"BatchID":"31-a1eac15c","BatchType":"Conversion","CreatedDate":"2018-12-19T11:51:18.577","IsBatchCompleted":false},
{"BatchID":"31-b3e8cc7e",BatchType":"","CreatedDate":"2018-12-19T10:18:51.27","IsBatchCompleted":false"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

Two things were needed. Had to remove the empty `tbody` tag. And change `columnDefs` to `columns`. And yes, the `s` in `columns` is very important. That was my mistake when I did this the first time.